# What is wrong with this function generator simulation?

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, function-generator

I was trying to make a function generator using op amps, and I am supposed to get square waveform as output of the second stage and a triangular waveform as the output of the first waveform. But when I simulate the circuit in LTSpice, I am getting a constant voltage of around 14 V as output. What am I doing wrong?[image]

Comment: The total simulation time may be too large compared to the period of the oscillations so, even if you used `startup`, the timestep may have gotten too large by the time the oscillations actually started, resulting in the solver thinking there are none, to begin with. Try simulating for `1m` or so. Increase/decrease as needed. Or, don't use `startup` and add `ic=1` to `C1`, e.g. the value will look like `0.1u ic=1` (`startup` acts on both supplies and they mey be too symmetrical for something unusual to ahppen). Yet another thing is you could use a different opamp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just one change to make to get oscillations. The 2nd stage must not be an inverting amplifier, but a schmitt:

[image: revised schematic]